# Progressive web app (PWA) not showing install button in browser bar

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I need to create a PWA application. Everything works on the phone, but for some reason the browser does not offer the option in the address bar to install the application onto the computer. What could this be related to?

Web manifest:

```json
{
  "name": "Cars",
  "description": "Autos",
  "start_url": "/",
  "lang": "ru",
  "display": "standalone",

  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/android-icon-36x36.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "0.75"
    },
    {
      "src": "/android-icon-48x48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "src": "/android-icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "1.5"
    },
    {
      "src": "/android-icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "2.0"
    },
    {
      "src": "/android-icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "3.0"
    },
    {
      "src": "/android-icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "4.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to change the manifest somehow via ChatGPT, but nothing happens. I don't understand what could be the matter.

Answer (score 0):

To make your app insallable it must:

- Have an icon
- Have a service worker
- Be served via HTTPS
- Have manifest file

Full list of requirements can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Tutorials/js13kGames/Installable_PWAs).

Comment: I just have it all. even on the phone it is installed, but for some reason the browser does not offer to install pwa in the address bar of the computer

Comment: @niobium04 I looked at [webmanifest specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) and it says there are no `lang` or `icons.density` properties allowed. Try to delete them.